# COMO SOLUCIONAR EL HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, formularios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:44360/>[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar el programa, y buscar la dirección https://localhost:44360/, me genera la siguiente excepción, a pesar de no generar errores en el código, no me permite continuar con el programa:

Comment: deberias colocar todo el webconfig y no dos fotos. que no sirven para ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que en tu web.config tienes un espacio connection**s**trings en vez de connection**S**trings.

El error 500 es un error en la programación que no es visible al cliente, es decir, del lado del servidor. Tu archivo de configuración parece tener ese pequeño error, lo que perfectamente encaja con error 500.